# deduce amount issue, not the same value foreach execute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some issue in deduce amount between two variables, this issue is that it concatain the previous val plus the new one.

Exemple :

```
<div id="total">200.00</div>
<input id="amount"/> //value = 100 for exemple

jQuery("input#amount").on("keydown",function search(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) { //when hit Enter
        var $myval = jQuery(this).val();    
        var obj = [
            {"id":1, "code": 100, "value":20}
        ];

        var item = obj.find(key => key.code === $myval);
        if (item) {
            var newTotal = jQuery("#total").text() - item.value;
        }
    }
}
```

Info : I don't have this issue when I refresh a page, but without I'm having this problem.

With the code: the first execute, it's deduce well `200 - 20`

The second time it's deduce not `20` but `40`, the third `60` whereas he should deduce 20 for each time according to this value `"value":20` . Have you an idea Why ?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/skcvybmg/1/) the real exemple.

Comment: maybe, this function is running twice, three times... put a `console.log` to verify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you got rebind issue in your jquery codes, you can simply use unbind to resolve the issue.

hopefully my snippet can help you in some way..
have a nice day!

```js
jQuery("input#barcode").on("keydown",function search(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            var ticketValue = jQuery(this).val();
            console.log("Ticket n°= "+ticketValue);
            var obj = [
                {"id":1, "code":"123", "valeur":20},
                {"id":2, "code":"456", "valeur":30},
                {"id":3, "code":"789", "valeur":15},
                {"id":4, "code":"1011", "valeur":25}
            ];
            var item = obj.find(key => key.code === ticketValue);
            if (item) {
                jQuery('#barcode').prop('disabled', true);
                jQuery("#output, #output-execute-yes, #output-execute-no").css('display', 'block');
                jQuery("#output").html("Ticket ok !"+"<br>"+"Value : "+item.valeur);
                jQuery('#barcode').val('');

                //deduce Amount from total
                
                //use unbind to resolve rebind issue
                jQuery("#output-execute-yes").unbind().click(function() {
                    var newTotal = jQuery("#amount span").text() - item.valeur;
                    jQuery("#amount span").html(newTotal.toFixed(2));
                    jQuery("#output, #output-execute-yes, #output-execute-no").css('display', 'none');
                    jQuery('#barcode').prop('disabled', false);
                });

                jQuery("#output-execute-no").unbind().click(function() {
                    jQuery("#output, #output-execute-yes, #output-execute-no").css('display', 'none');
                    jQuery('#barcode').prop('disabled', false);
                });

            } else {
                jQuery("#output").css('display', 'block');
                jQuery("#output-execute-yes, #output-execute-no").css('display', 'none');
                jQuery("#output").html("Ticket ko !");
                jQuery('#barcode').val('');
            }
        }
    });
```

```css
h3 {
        text-align: center;
        color: #c81113;
    }
    #barcode {
        padding: 10px;
        border: none;
        border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
        width: 30%;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #909090;
    }
    #amount {
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
        width: 15%;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
        float: right;
    }
    #amount span {
        font-size: 28px;
        color: #c81113;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    #output {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 22px;
        border: 1px solid #7d7d7d;
        padding: 10px;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #7d7d7d;
        margin-top: 30px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        width: 50%;
        display: block;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
    }
    #crediter {
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
        width: 6%;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
        float: right;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #output-execute-yes, #output-execute-no {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #c81113;
        padding: 8px;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #c81113;
        margin-top: 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        width: 25%;
        display: block;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    div.info {
     padding-top: 43px;
     font-size: 11px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
Val <input id="barcode" type="text" class="barcode" autofocus="autofocus" onfocus="this.select()"/>
<div id="amount"><span>200.00</span></div>
<div id="output" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="output-execute-yes" style="display:none;">Yes, I decude</div>
<div id="output-execute-no" style="display:none;">No, I don't deduce</div>

<div class="info">info; try to enter "123", it deduce 20, then enter "123" again, it deduce 40 and not 20 !</div>
```

Comment: the `unbind()` solved my issue, thanks for your time.